# std::thread error "no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, c++17

So I am currently making a program that can copy and paste files using WinForms.

What I want is to run the copy process on another thread like this:

```
// #include <filesystem> and #include <thread>

std::thread t2(std::filesystem::copy, 
    std::string(context->marshal_as<const char*>(SourceTBox->Text)) + "\\" + 
    i.path().filename().generic_u8string(), 
    std::string(context->marshal_as<const char*>(DestinationTBox->Text)));
```

But I get the following error:

> E0289 no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the
> argument list argument types are: (<unknown-type>,
> <error-type>)

I browsed other threads and tried the solutions there, but nothing seems to work.
Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `copy`, even `std::thread t2(std::filesystem::copy, std::string("a.txt"), std::string("b.txt"));` does not work https://godbolt.org/z/1nsfbY44o

Comment: since `std::filesystem::copy` is an overloaded function, you have to define the overload you want to use, like this `std::thread t(static_cast<void(*)(const std::filesystem::path&, const std::filesystem::path&)>(std::filesystem::copy), "<path from>", "<path to>");`